# How can I resolve the webpack "unmet peer dependency" warning for my create-react-app package?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, dependencies

[`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) (CRA) is a command-line tool that helps you set up a new React app. It creates a `package.json` that includes a `react-scripts` dependency.

The `react-scripts` package has a `webpack` dependency (currently version `4.19.1`.)

[`craco`](https://github.com/sharegate/craco) is a library that makes it easy to configure `create-react-app`.

I've released a [`craco-less`](https://github.com/FormAPI/craco-less) package, which is a `craco` plugin. It makes it easy to set up Less support for `create-react-app`. The `craco-less` dependencies include the `css-loader` and `style-loader` packages, and *these* packages have `webpack@^4.0.0` in their `peerDependencies`.

When I install the `craco-less` package (`yarn add craco-less`), I get the following warnings:

```
warning "craco-less > css-loader@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning "craco-less > less-loader@4.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
```

I tried adding this to my `package.json`:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "webpack": "^4.0.0"
}
```

But this just gave me an extra warning:

```
warning "craco-less > css-loader@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning "craco-less > less-loader@4.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning " > craco-less@1.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
```

I also tried adding `webpack` as an explicit dependency, and this works 90% of the time, but sometimes causes `create-react-app` to crash with the error described [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/FormAPI/craco-less/issues/3):

[image: npm package crash]

(Only seems to happen with `npm install`, and not `yarn install`.)

I just realized that this error happens because `react-scripts` depends on a specific webpack version, and my package has a loose dependency (`^4.0.0`). But I would have expected the `react-scripts` dependency to override this loose version constraint and install `4.19.1` instead of the latest version (`4.27.1`). I think this is why it's working with `yarn` and not with `npm`, because maybe `yarn` has smarter dependency resolution.

My library has a dependency on `"react-scripts": "^2.1.1"` (flexible), so I want to know if there is a way to delegate to their `webpack` dependency instead of installing the latest version?

It would be a pain to specify `4.19.1` as a hardcoded version, because I would have to update the `craco-less` library all the time whenever they update the `react-scripts` package. Or maybe I could write a script to just automate these updates if it can't be done in the `package.json`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
yarn upgrade webpack@^4.0.0
```

[Reference](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1078)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Had a few devs sink a fair bit of time into this, we eventually swapped over to Yarn. Jenkins required a few tweaks:

Build Environment:

```
Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH

NodeJS Installation: 8.10
```

Version >8

Preface Exe Shell with:

```
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -s
export PATH=$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH

yarn install
yarn run build
```